# TimelinePlot y-axis Misaligned

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

When plotting an `Association` of data in `TimelinePlot` the y-axis is labeled with the `Keys`.  However the axis is not aligned to the data.

```
TimelinePlot@
 AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"}, ConstantArray[{{2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 1, 10}}, 3]]
```

[image]

I would turn off the y-axis with `Axes` but `TimelinePlot` ignores the y-axis specification.

```
TimelinePlot[
 AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"}, ConstantArray[{{2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 1, 10}}, 3]], 
 Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

Does anyone else get this? Any ideas to have the y-axis align or remove it altogether? Actually, clicking on the y-axis seems to indicate the it is not an *axis*.  So ...

Mma 11.1.1 on Win 7 Ent

Comment: Look at the `InputForm` and you'll see it's *definitely* not an axis, it's an `Inset`.  You could do something like ```TimelinePlot[
  AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"}, 
   ConstantArray[{{2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 1, 10}}, 3]], 
  PlotLayout -> "Stacked", Frame -> True] /. 
 Inset[Graphics[prims_, opts__], moreOpts__] :> ReplaceAll[
   prims, {0, y_Integer} :> {AbsoluteTime[{2016, 12, 31}], y}]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as = AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"}, ConstantArray[{{2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 1, 10}}, 3]];
```

To remove the labels you can use

```
 tlp = TimelinePlot[Values @ as] (* or *)
 tlp = TimelinePlot[as]/. _Inset->Nothing
```

[image]

To add labels on the y axis:

```
Show[tlp, Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, 
  Options[tlp, FrameTicks] /. {None, None} -> {MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #}&, Keys[as]], None}]
```

[image]

**Note:** For thegeneral case where `Spacings -> spacings` option specified, tick specification above should change to

```
MapIndexed[{#2[[1]] spacings[[#2[[1]]]], #}&, Keys[as]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way the ref/[`TimelinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimelinePlot.html) recommends making a time-list-plot with an association.

```
TimelinePlot @
  AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"}, 
  ConstantArray[Interval[{{2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 1, 10}}], 3]]
```

[image: plot]

Note the use of `Interval`.

The plot looks strange because the data is highly contrived, but the "a", "b", "c" labels give valuable information on mouse-over. The keys are not axes labels, but labels for the timelines.